# PopupMenu without anchor view?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, contextmenu, popupmenu, anchor-view

I have a `RecyclerView`, in which long press on `ItemView` showing a `Popupmenu`. My issue is that if the item longer than parent height ( top and bottom end will not visible on the screen without scroll ). then I click on the center of the app causing  `Unable to create a layer for PopupWindow$PopupBackgroundView'` exception and app going force closed. I think the issue is that Popupmenu not getting its anchor space. Do anyone know `Popupmenu` without Anchor View?

Comment: so did you see [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu)?

Comment: yes, it's an good option but am inflating view from menu.xml. and it's in recyclerview

Comment: PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(view.getContext(), view);popup.inflate(R.menu.menu_popup_content_comment);

Comment: simply call `Activity#registerForContextMenu` and override `Activity#onCreateContextMenu` - you can add your items "by hand" or use `MenuInflater` for that

Comment: in RecyclerView.Adapter ??

Comment: then how can i add itemClick for menuinflator ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Popup menu**

> A popup menu displays a list of items in a vertical list that's
>   anchored to the view that invoked the menu. It's good for providing an
>   overflow of actions that relate to specific content or to provide
>   options for a second part of a command. Actions in a popup menu should
>   not directly affect the corresponding content—that's what contextual
>   actions are for. Rather, the popup menu is for extended actions that
>   relate to regions of content in your activity.
>   Especially you can't